# Execute code after Django init

Tags: python, django, startup

I have a bunch of apps, that may or may not contains a file called `activity.py`. This file basically registers model signals. It works well when I import this file in the `ready` method of the `AppConfig` class. The problem is I have a dozen app, so I don't want to have this same method in all my apps :

```
def ready(self):
    # register signal for activity feed
    from . import activity
```

I would like to run a script that will through the `INSTALLED_APPS` array, and if this app contains a file `activity.py`, import it.
I can't find a way to run a function for when all the apps are ready, and before the server is listening.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is create another app whose only purpose will be to perform that initialization and put it in `INSTALLED_APPS`. In that app, subclass [`AppConfig`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/) and override the [`AppConfig.ready()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following approach:

```
from django.conf import settings
from importlib import import_module

for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    module_name = '%s.%s' % (app, "activity")
    try:
        import_module(module_name)
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

Comment: When do I run this code ? All the models must be instantiated first